# How can make the index of an array revert back to 0 once it is greater than the length

Tags: javascript, html

```js
class Question {
    constructor(question, ansA, ansB, ansC, ansD, answer) {
        this.question = question;
        this.ansA = ansA;
        this.ansB = ansB;
        this.ansC = ansC;
        this.ansD = ansD;
        this.answer = answer;
    }

    checkAns(ansSelected, answer) {
        if (ansSelected === answer) {
            console.log('Well Done')
        }
    }
};

var questionOne = new Question('Where is Creete?', 'Barcalona', 'Greece', 'Dubi', 'Ireland', 'Greece');
var questionTwo = new Question('How many times have Liverppool won the Champions Legue?', '1', '4', '6', '5', '6');

var i = 0;
const arrayQuestion = [questionOne, questionTwo];




//Displaying the first index of the question array on load up
document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].question;
document.getElementById('A').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansA;
document.getElementById('B').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansB;
document.getElementById('C').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansC;
document.getElementById('D').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansD;



//Next button which cycles through the array and show the current question.
const n = document.getElementById('n');
n.addEventListener("click", next);
function next (){
    
    
    if( i > arrayQuestion.length){
        i === 0;
    }
    
    i++;
    
    
    document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].question;
    document.getElementById('A').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansA;
    document.getElementById('B').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansB;
    document.getElementById('C').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansC;
    document.getElementById('D').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansD;

};





function prev (){
    i--;
    
    
    document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].question;
    document.getElementById('A').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansA;
    document.getElementById('B').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansB;
    document.getElementById('C').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansC;
    document.getElementById('D').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansD;
    
}
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-weight: 200;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

button{
    background: blue;
    padding: 1.2em;
    margin: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <form>
            <h2 id="question"></h2>
            <button id="A" class="userSelection"></button>
            <button id="B" class="userSelection"></button>
            <button id="C" class="userSelection"></button>
            <button id="D" class="userSelection"></button>
            <button id="p" type="button" class="userSelection">P</button>
            <button id="n" type="button" class="userSelection">N</button>

        </form>
    </body>
    <script src = js/app.js></script>
</html>
```

I am trying to cycle through an array which holds questions Objects.

I am doing this using a next and previous button to display questions.

I want to know how to go back to index 0 once the array.length has been reached.

Right now I am getting an error as the array index goes out of bounds.

I have tried to add an if statement so when the index is greater than the array.length the index reverts back to 0.

```
<JS>

//The questions are objects which are created using a class constructor
//Then stored in an array to use later
var questionOne = new Question('Where is Creete?', 'Barcalona', 'Greece', 'Dubi', 'Ireland', 'Greece');
var questionTwo = new Question('How many times have Liverppool won the Champions Legue?', '1', '4', '6', '5', '6');

var i = 0;
const arrayQuestion = [questionOne, questionTwo];




//Displaying the first index of the question array on load up
document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].question;
document.getElementById('A').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansA;
document.getElementById('B').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansB;
document.getElementById('C').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansC;
document.getElementById('D').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansD;



//Next button which cycles through the array and show the current question.
const n = document.getElementById('n');
n.addEventListener("click", next);
function next (){


    if( i > arrayQuestion.length){
        i === 0;
    }

    i++;

    //Displaying the next index in the array
    document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = 
    arrayQuestion[i].question;
    document.getElementById('A').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansA;
    document.getElementById('B').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansB;
    document.getElementById('C').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansC;
    document.getElementById('D').innerHTML = arrayQuestion[i].ansD;

};
```

The expected result is once the next button is clicked and it is greater than the length of the array it will revert to index 0.

The if statement I have created does not seem to work it throws the error

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'question' of undefined`

I understand why but I am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: `if( i > arrayQuestion.length){` Off-by-one error. `arr[arr.length]` will be `undefined` as well, arrays are zero-indexed

Comment: I know that they are zero indexed and I have i set to 0, my function increments it but when it reaches its limit I get the out of bounds error, that is the point of the question i do not know the syntax to make it revert

Comment: You almost have it, you just have an off-by-one error

Comment: Is it something to do with the `if`` statement being in the same function as when it increments i?

Comment: No, the problem is that your `if( i > arrayQuestion.length){` is fulfilled one iteration too late

Comment: I thought the JS engine read line by line though so I can not see why if I put the `if` statement after the increment why it does not reset

Comment: Because your test is wrong. If you reset after the increment, you need to reset when `i === arrayQuestion.length`, not if `i > arrayQuestion.length`

Comment: @CertainPerformance , Thanks for the help and making me think and work a bit I understand now and have learned something as well. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `%` modulo operation

```
function safeGet(array, i) {
    return array[i % array.length];
}
```

and use this like this:

```
safeGet(['a', 'b', 'c'], 0);  // 'a'
safeGet(['a', 'b', 'c'], 1);  // 'b'
safeGet(['a', 'b', 'c'], 2);  // 'c'
safeGet(['a', 'b', 'c'], 3);  // 'a'
safeGet(['a', 'b', 'c'], 4);  // 'b'
safeGet(['a', 'b', 'c'], 5);  // 'c'
safeGet(['a', 'b', 'c'], 6);  // 'a'
```